# MVC Repositories - Dependency Injection Helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

I have a typical repository that implements the respective interface :

```
public class AccountRepository : IAccountRepository, IDisposable
{
....
```

Meanwhile inside this repository I am using a static helper class. What's the correct approach to static classes ? Since they cannot implement interfaces?

I want my repository to be decoupled (DI pattern), but I don't know how to apply it to static classes that my repository use.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have an issue with the static classes in your repository class. A repository class is generally used to decouple your data access code from the rest of your application. This essentially allows you to replace your data access provider without to much effort by re-implementing your concrete repository classes for a new data access provider.

You can use DI to inject your repository class into either your controller or a service class.

If you really want to get your head around DI I would recommend reading "Dependency Injection in .Net" by Mark Seeman.

Comment: I see what you mean, but if my repository is using other classes that are not passed to it through the constructor, is it decoupled ? How can I mock my interfaces to supply to it and then the repository is calling other static classes inside? THanks

Comment: If the reason you are trying to decouple the dependencies within your repository is to make it easier to test using TDD, one thing to consider is that when you are testing a repository you are testing across a system boundary (i.e. you are now communicating with a database, xml file, etc) so your tests are no longer true unit tests. They are integration tests so you shouldn't be as concerned about testing the logic within the method in isolation. Even if you pull out all the dependencies within your repository at some point you will need to cross the system boundary and access the database.